# Android video sync across multiple devices

Tags: android, video

I need to play 6 different videos on 6 different android devices and have the videos stay in synch once started.

Can anybody point me in the right direction to a possible solution, some sample code, even a keyword would be useful since "video sync" tends to just bring up syncing personal videos between device and computer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I highly doubt you are going to find any code samples for this as it is very specific. My google search also turned up nothing. Oh and wait, I just re-read it, how would 6 DIFFERENT videos stay in sync if they are all different lengths? What exactly are you trying to accomplish? I could understand 1 video staying syncd across multiple devices, but 6 videos?

Comment: Assume they have different content/files, but are the same length.  The end result is a video wall basically.  The videos would loop.  I doubt my chances of finding sample code, but it never hurts to ask.  Just clues where to look for the start and maintenance of a loop like this would be ideal.  Any form of clue would be ideal actually.

Answer (score 1):

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.cbase.blinkendroid

Seems to do the job, and then some. Haven't tried it though. 
They have a google code page somewhere too.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar need that I've been thinking about how to do it. You'll need some server side code. This is what I'm considering right now:

Have a service on the server that takes in a time stamp from the device and returns an adjusted start time back to the device, based off the delta between the device time and the server time. In other words, the absolute start time would come from the server.

I haven't tried this yet, but I think it might work.

Comment: this is not an answer.  this is a comment.  please update to avoid flagging.  tks!  :) tg